# Node.js Promise Chain not firing in desired order

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I created a simple example of a Promise chain. My goal is to fire the 4 functions below to get the output in Order. i.e. 1 2 3 4.

```
function WriteOne()
{
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
    {
        console.log("1");
        resolve("true");
    })    
}

function WriteTwo()
{
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
    {
        setTimeout(function(){console.log("2");}, 3000);
        resolve("true");
    })    
}

function WriteThree()
{
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
    {
        setTimeout(function(){console.log("3");}, 1000);
        resolve("true");
    })
}

function WriteFour()
{
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
    {
        console.log("4");
        resolve("true");
    }) 
}

WriteOne().then(WriteTwo).then(WriteThree).then(WriteFour);
```

When I execute them, they are firing in this order:

```
1 4 3 2
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: the promise is being resolved immediately, it's not waiting for the timeouts, hence 1 logs first, then 4 is logged since it's the second instantly called, then 3 logs after 1 second, then 2 after 3 seconds. Place the resolve after your console logs, inside the timeout, and everything will work as expected.

Comment: The promises are firing in the correct order, but you have setTimeout calls in Two and Three. The Promises don't wait for them. To do that, you need to call `resolve` in the timeout callback.

Comment: You might want to check [Sleeping in JavaScript](https://medium.com/@nino.filiu/sleeping-in-javascript-e00a1ebbde2e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `resolve` inside `setTimeout` callback

```js
function WriteOne() {
 return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  console.log("1");
  resolve("true");
 });
}

function WriteTwo() {
 return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function () {
   console.log("2");
   resolve("true");
  }, 3000);
  
 });
}

function WriteThree() {
 return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function () {
   console.log("3");
   resolve("true");
  }, 1000);
  
 });
}

function WriteFour() {
 return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  console.log("4");
  resolve("true");
 });
}

WriteOne().then(WriteTwo).then(WriteThree).then(WriteFour);
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong here, here what's happening:

```
// t=0s
writeOne()
// 1 is logged
// promise is resolved
.then(writeTwo)
// in 3s, 2 will be logged
// promise is resolved
.then(writeThree)
// in 1s, 3 will be logged
// promise is resolved
.then(writeFour)
// 4 is logged

// t=1s
// 3 is logged

// t=3s
// 2 is logged
```

Thus the output.

To get the result you're expecting, resolve the promise inside the setTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

`resolve("true")` is called before the `console.log()` because it's outside the `setTimeout()`.

Since `WriteOne()` and `WriteFour()` have no timeout, "1" and "4" appear first. Then "3" 1 second later, Then 2.

You have to put `resolve("true");` inside `setTimeout()` in order to have them appear... in order.